# List data structure for block storage

Tags: c++, database, algorithm, list, data-structures

My program has a storage: a file, divided by a pages 4...16Kb.

The storage keeps number of items, each has different size. The items are stored each after another with the order they were added to a storage (no index, no sorting). This series of items occupy a number of pages, each page has 100...300 items (because of different size of an item).

Each item can be addressed by 2 numbers: (page_number, index_in_a_page).

I am looking for a data structure and an algorithm to organize a list of these items. That algorithm should allow moving any item from its current position to the top of a list using minimum page writes. I expect this data structure will be stored in the same sort of pages and i would like minimum page writes per single item move.

Also there is a fault-tolerance concerns: page write is atomic (using double-write-buffer) but 2 writes are not, so transactions, journalling and so on comes to scene.

For now i am examining journaling approach: each action just leave single journal record and when the journal gets critical mass, its executed on real pages.

Comment: I wonder why you want to "move item from current position to the top of the list". Are you implementing a simple database using C++?

Comment: @pwwpche i am implementing a simple database for specific data and specific operations on them. I am doing this just for fun. "Moving element from current position to the top of the list" is used for discussion board -- i need to update discussion and display it before other discussions where new message is added there.

Comment: I guess your solution is to delete this updated item from the page it was in, created a new item, and add it to some page. If so, do you have any unique "index" for an item, just like the "primary key" of a row in a database? Because if you have, you can use B-tree data to reorganize your data, which might take less page writes.